# Want the general idea of how proof works (Prove that $V=R(T^k) \oplus N(T^k)$ for some positive integer k.)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, operator-theory

> Let V be a finite-dimensional vector space, and let $T:V \rightarrow V$ be linear.

Prove that $V=R(T^k) \oplus N(T^k)$ for some positive integer k.

For this problem, I just can't get the gist of it. I know that we can extend $V=R(T^k) \oplus N(T^k)$ to Rank-nullity theorem, and by that theorem we can see that rank is finite dimensional and is within a certain range. Can someone tell the general idea of how the proof works for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hints:**

The direct sum $V=R(T^k)\oplus N(T^k)$ means that every element of $V$ can be written as a sum of elements from $R(T^k)$ and from $N(T^k)$, and that the intersection $N(T^k)\cap R(T^k)$ is $=\left\{0\right\}$.

Let's leave it as an exercise that if $N(T^k)\cap R(T^k)=\left\{0\right\}$, then the first condition holds automatically.

Now note that there is an integer $k$ such that $N(T^k)=N(T^{2k})$ (why?). Fix this $k$. Then take $x\in N(T^k)\cap R(T^k)$. Since $x\in R(T^k)$, there is $y\in V$ such that $x=T^k(y)$. Since $x\in N(T^k)$, we see $T^{2k}(y)=0$. Since $N(T^k)=N(T^{2k})$, it follows that $x=T^k(y)=0$. Therefore $N(T^k)\cap R(T^k)=\left\{0\right\}$.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do we prove the existence of that integer k? Is it because $T: V  \rightarrow V$?

Comment: Notice that $N(T^1)\subseteq N(T^2)\subseteq\ldots$. So their dimensions form an increasing sequence. Since $V$ is finite-dimensional, it must stop.

Comment: I see, thanks. Do you have a reference book you recommend so I can study on this specific topic?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a specific linear algebra book to recommend. Maybe doing more exercises (from the text-books perhaps) will help.